# Is there a way to push all bookmarks to another repo, all at once? (Mercurial)

Tags: mercurial

I am importing one Mercurial repo into another, maintaining history. There are several bookmarked heads on the default branch, and I want those bookmarked heads to still be bookmarked in the new, merged repo. As far as I can tell, the two ways to do this is to either,

1. pull each bookmark individually
2. pull the entire thing and recreate the bookmarks by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-B parameter can be used in push any amount of times. Full bookmarks list for repo you can get from `hg bookmarks`

Comment: Not ideal, but simple enough to run a regex replace on the output of `hg bookmarks` to get the list.

Answer (score 3):

Extending the previous answer, here's how to push all branches using awk and the output of hg bookmarks in bash:

```
hg bookmarks | awk '{if (NF == 3) print $2; else print $1;}' | xargs -n 1 hg push -f -B
```

Comment: I made it faster (does not call hg once per bookmark). `hg bookmarks | awk '{if (NF == 3) print "-B " $2; else print "-B " $1;}' | xargs hg push`

Comment: Would appreciate if anyone can get this to also remove bookmarks, when they are removed locally.

Answer (score 1):

Unix:

```
hg push $(hg bookmarks -T "-B {bookmark} ")
```

Windows:

```
for /f "delims=" %A in ('hg bookmarks -T "-B {bookmark} "') do @hg push %A
```

PowerShell:

```
hg bookmarks -T "{bookmark}\n" | %{ Write-Host === Bookmark $_ === ; hg push -B $_ }
```